# Не работает асинхронный action, Redux Thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Делаю запрос на сервер в асинхронном action. Но асинхронный action не запускается. Redux Thunk подключаю, @babel/polyfill подключаю. Хук useEffect срабатывает, а асинхронный action - нет. Синхронные actions работают нормально. Не понимаю, что я делаю не так?

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import '@babel/polyfill'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux"
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
'import {reducer} from "./redux/reducer"
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import App from './App.js'

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

App.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {fetchData} from "./redux/actions'

export default function () {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
}
```

actions.js

```
export const fetchData = () => async dispatch => {
    console.log('fetchData');  //не выводится
    const res =  await fetch("url");
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: res.json()
    });
};
```

Comment: а как связаны fetchData и fetchExchangeRateCoefficientAndDelivery?

Comment: Опечатка.Везде одинаковое название

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что когда Вы создали асинхронный *action*, то его нужно не просто вызывать, а *диспатчить*. например:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'; // подключаем хук для диспатча
import {fetchData} from "./redux/actions';

export default function () {
    const dispatch = useDispatch(); // создаем сам диспатч

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchData()); // вызываем fetchData уже как аргумент для dispatch
    }, []);
}
```

наверное, стоит объяснить почему Вы ошиблись.

используя метод `connect` в классовых компонентах, Вы вызывали Ваши асинхронные *actions* без явного вызова в `dispatch` (то есть, просто `fetchData()`). это потому, что внутри `connect` сам уже оборачивал Ваши асинхронные *actions*. например:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchData };
```

это на самом деле сокращенный вариант для

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchData: () => {
        dispatch(fetchData())
    }
});
```

как Вы выдите, здесь `connect` будет за Вас оборачивать Ваш `fetchData` в    `dispatch`.

в функциональных компонентах Вам нужно **самому вручную** это делать.

---

---

и заметил, что Вы внутри Вашего `fetchData` передаете в payload `res.json()`. это неправильно, так как `res.json()` возвращает промис. лучше сделать так:

```
export const fetchData = () => async dispatch => {
    console.log('fetchData');  //не выводится
    const res =  await fetch("url");
    const result = await res.json(); // распарсить значение здесь
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: result  // передать уже готовое значение
    });
};
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! И все заработало и стало понятно. Вы - супер!